# jQuery - map array parts to HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple Ajax request that's rapidly becoming more and more unsimple!

Basically it posts some data (a product code) and returns an array of similar codes, and I need to display each array element as a `button` within a `btn-group`.

*Please bear in mind that this Ajax request is run for each code found (not usually more than a couple).*

### Required result:

Each element in the array should be returned as a `<button>` element within a `.btn-group` `div`. The first `btn` should contain the original (returned using `data.code`).

So, for two AJAX requests, it should appear something like:
[image: required result - two btn-groups]

### So far:

It splits it into a new `btn-group` for each code in the array. I can see where I've gone wrong in the code but I can't work out how it should be. The below JS returns this:
[image: split into six separate btn-groups]

### My AJAX success function:

```
// AJAX function above here...
success: function(data) {
     if (!data.result) {
          $('#importerrors').append(
                data.rarray.map(function(erow) {
                return $('<div class="btn-group" style="margin:10px!important;"><button class="btn btn-danger">'+ data.code +'</button>').append(
                $.map(erow, function(cell) {
                     return $('<button class="btn btn-success retry-code">').text(cell);
                })
                );
                })
            );
      } else {
          //  other stuff
      }
}
```

*I've had a good look around similar questions on SO but nothing seems to help! Would really appreciate any help on this - thanks!*

---

### EDIT:

`console.log` as suggested by @naortor below returns the following:

**`data.rarray`:**

```
rarray: Array(3)
0: Object
    > code: "FAIGGHVD "
      __proto__: Object
1: Object
    > code: "GG500"
      __proto__: Object
2: Object
    > code: "GGC4"
      __proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: how does `data` looks like?

Comment: @naortor - if you mean `data.rarray` it's returned from the PHP file as `$rarray[] = array('code' => $row['va_code']);` and should always have three elements, so i.e. `'FAIGGHVD, GG500,GGC4'`

Comment: Really appreciate some more help on this if possible! @naortor

Comment: its a bit hard to help because your question isn't clear enough - can you add to your question the result of `console.log(data)` and of `console.log(data.rarray)` ?

Comment: @naortor - have edited my question to suit. Hopefully all the data you were looking for I've shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would solved it:

```
$('#importerrors').append('<div class="btn-group" style="margin:10px!important;"><button class="btn btn-danger">'+ data.code +'</button></div>').find('div:last-child').append(
    $.map(rarray, function(cell) {
         return $('<button class="btn btn-success retry-code">').text(cell.code);
    })
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8xqwydsn/1/